# Calling SSRS Report From Asp.net Pages

Tags: asp.net, sql, c#-3.0

```
        ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ProcessingMode.Remote;
        ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri(Keys.ReportServerUrl);
        ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportPath = Keys.ReportPath + "RptTest";

        ReportViewer1.ShowParameterPrompts = false;
        ReportViewer1.ShowCredentialPrompts = false;
        IReportServerCredentials irsc = new CustomReportCredentials();
        ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials = irsc;
        ReportViewer1.ServerReport.Refresh();
```

...............................................
CustomReportCredentials Class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Utilities;


/// <summary>
/// Summary description for CustomReportCredentials
/// </summary>
/// [Serializable]
public class CustomReportCredentials : Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.IReportServerCredentials
{


    private string _UserName;
    private string _PassWord;
    private string _DomainName;

    #region IReportServerCredentials Members
    public CustomReportCredentials()
    {
        _UserName = "";
        _PassWord = "";
        _DomainName = "";
    }

    public bool GetFormsCredentials(out System.Net.Cookie authCookie, out string userName, out string password, out string authority)
    {
      authCookie = null;
      userName = null;
      password = null;
      authority = null;

      return false;
    }

    public WindowsIdentity ImpersonationUser
    {
            get
            {

                System.Security.Principal.WindowsImpersonationContext impersonationContext = null;
                System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity currentWindowsIdentity = null;
                            currentWindowsIdentity = (System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;
                impersonationContext = currentWindowsIdentity.Impersonate();

                //Insert your code that runs under the security context of the authenticating user here.

                impersonationContext.Undo();

                return currentWindowsIdentity; // not use ImpersonationUser
                }
    }

    public System.Net.ICredentials NetworkCredentials
    {
      get
      {
        string userName = "";
        string domainName = "";
        string password = "";

        return new System.Net.NetworkCredential(userName, password, domainName);
      }
    }

    #endregion

}
```

Comment: What is your question? You seem to have the code to "call" a report.

Comment: What is - "How do I call an SSRS report from ASP .NET, Alex?"